# Where can I see what Community♦ did to a question?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, community

Sometimes a question pops up on the [main page](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/) with the last touch being done by the [Community♦](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) user (e.g. `2h ago Community♦ 1`). But if you click on the question itself you don't see any modification by [Community♦](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) at all. I vaguely remember that this *can* happen when questions are poked to float to the top of the main page --- for example when some algorithm decides a question hasn't received enough attention.

It would be nice if all actions by [Community♦](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) were visible on the respective "/revisions" page of a question. Note that some actions (e.g. tweets) *are* visible even though they don't actually edit or revise the question.

Comment: So you want to see the "invisible magic bump" on the revisions page?

Comment: @Kevin: Basically, yes. In general, there should be no silent activity on a question.

Comment: LOL... great minds.... http://meta.politics.stackexchange.com/questions/217/what-does-it-mean-that-community-modified-a-question

Comment: @DVK: Yours seems to be ahead of mine by about two weeks :)

Comment: I was also thinking about this earlier this week.  Ward's answer isn't really satisfying to me as there seemed to be an unusually large number of them a few days ago.

Comment: @AnnaLear: How is this *support*? It's clearly something that cannot be accessed by the existing tools (judging from the answers). So, it's the request for a feature. It's your prerogative to *decline* it, but it's still a feature-request.

Comment: @bitmask The subject line made it sound more like a support request to me. The answer just happens to be "you can't see that anywhere because it's not a revision-like activity". I'm happy to retag back, if you feel strongly about it, though.

Comment: @AnnaLear: I wouldn't go so far to say that I feel strongly about it, but since it doesn't qualify as a support question it's a nice-to-have feature-request.

Answer (score 4):

Poking a random old question every hour is one of the functions [Community](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) performs.  Since the question isn't actually changed, I don't think it's necessary to include "bumping" on the revision page.